# Find A using the inverse of B from AB.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm given that $$AB = \begin{bmatrix}5&4\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix}7&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The question asks me to find $A$ using $B^{-1}.\,$ I know that $$B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\-2&7\end{bmatrix}.$$ Where do I go from here?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the product of $AB$ by $B^{-1}$ : $(AB)B^{-1}=A(BB^{-1})=AI=A.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** To cancel a $B$ you need to multiply by $B^{-1}$.

Cancel a $B$ from $AB$ to get $A$.